# Properly setting up coffee script with my ruby on rails page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

Im looking at the basic guide on [how to use javascript in ROR.](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)
I am familiar with javascipt (and jquery) but not really with coffee script.

The guide is pretty straightforward. Im just missing where i should place my coffee script for it to work.

I am trying to make the

```
paintIt = (element, backgroundColor, textColor) ->
  element.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
  if textColor?
    element.style.color = textColor
```

function work.

I place the

```
<a href="#" onclick="paintIt(this, '#990000')">Paint it red</a>
```

in my divider. And the code in my \assets\javascripts\pages.js.coffee  (although i tried putting basic javascript in the application.js as well) 
and then i run the server and nothing happens when i click on the link.

I am assuming i need to compile the coffee script and possibly link it to the page yet i have no idea how to do this. The guide says nothing about it and I dont know what to look for to make my script work

---

I want to set up the coffee script properly so it works in my page (I dont know if making the all the functions global is the way to go but im assuming its not)

I got the paintIt function to work by making it global with `window.paintIt =` as suggested in the comments.

It has the strange effect of only switching the background color for a second and then reverting it back to transparent background.

I can provide additional content of my files if you guys need more information.

Comment: CoffeeScript wraps everything in a self invoking function to prevent scope leakage. If you want `paintIt` in the global scope then you have to put it there by hand: `window.paintIt = ...` or `@paintIt = ...`.

Comment: Thanks this works but what is the proper way of setting coffee script up in ROR? Also it has a strange effect for altering the color only when the element is active (as soon as i let go of the mouse button the background color switches back) This is not how i understand this code should work...

Comment: Normally you'd do it more like http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4tLrs/ does, an `onclick` attribute is sort of stone age.

Comment: ah it doesnt work. I tried using the jQuery -> before your code but it didnt fix it. :( Also is there a way to use coffee script without making the functions global?

Comment: Yeah, don't use `onclick` attributes and you don't need global things. What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: I copy your code (the <a> tab into my home.html.erb file and the coffeescript into my pages.js.coffee file) and when i click on the link in my page nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add CoffeScript Rails integration gem by appending `gem 'coffee-rails'` to your `Gemfile`
2. Install dependencies by running `bundle`
3. Require your script in `application.js`

   ```
   //= require pages
   ```
4. Do not use onclick, set the click event handler in the JS code:

   ```
   paintIt = -> #....

   $ ->
     $('a').click -> paintIt(@, '#990000')
   ```

Comment: Its almost working. I was missing the //= require pages in my application.js. There is a bug however that when i click the link it flashes red once and then turns back to transparent background. On top of that when i click the link again it doesnt do anything.

Comment: Ill just post a new question about it.